# Send Hyperlink to call an api in Slack message

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

my question is very simple. I want to send a link/button with a slack message and when receiver click on that link it calls an api to perform some task. 
here is my code:

```
$msg = "hey! click to approve <a href='http://api2342.in/API/api.php'>Approve</a>";
self::sendSlackMessage($slackId,$msg);
```

I have this sendSlackMessage API to send a message to the Slack user which receives two parameters, and its working fine. I just need to figure out how to send a link to call an API to perform a certain task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy to do, just use the correct syntax for links in messages, which is `<http://www.foo.com|www.foo.com>`.

So for your example:

```
$msg = "hey! click to approve <http://api2342.in/API/api.php|Approve>";
```

Check out the excellent [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_urls) for more information on how to use links with Slack.

Or if you want to improve your user experience use [link buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#attaching_buttons_to_messages) instead of a naked link.