# I want to send a message with codes with an URL to hyperlink

Tags: python, slack

I have a python dataframe like this

```
Id Code Url
1   A   http://www.hello/1
2   B   http://www.hello/2
```

Where the url is a generic url with the id as difference.

What I want is to send a message via slack with the codes but linked to the url just to click them and redirect to the corresponding webpage.

Now I only can send the codes without URL, does somebody know how to create a list of the variable code with the hyperlink of url to send it via Slack?

The most important is to know how to create the hyperlink in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Hyperlink to call an api in Slack message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611493/send-hyperlink-to-call-an-api-in-slack-message)

Answer (score 0):

Found!

Easier than expected

```
sc.api_call(
  "chat.postMessage",
  channel='#channel_dummy',
  username='dummy_user',
  icon_emoji=':truck:',
  text=("Check it: " + '<' + url + row['Code'] + '|' + row['Code'] + '>')
)
```